# How do I access the StackExchange API authenticated methods from a perl script?

Tags: perl, mechanize, stackexchange-api

I'm using WWW::Mechanize. For the methods that do not require authentication, I get those as I would any other url, and then use the perl JSON module to parse out whatever data I want:

```
my $response = $mech->get('http://api.stackexchange.com/1.1/questions?fromdate=' . $lasthour)
my $q = from_json($response->content())
```

I've used Mechanize to log into websites in the past, but the Oauth stuff is confusing, and what [documentation is provided for using the API](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication) suggests that it is intended for web applications (that require registration with StackExchange?).

In particular, I am interested in the [notifications method](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/me-notifications) though I would expect the correct code to allow access to any of the auth-required methods.

Comment: ok, do you register your application? you must do that to use auth methods

Comment: I have now. What next? An answer with "this will only work after registration" and then instructions would have been welcome, I'd've upvoted that.

Comment: oh, I am not sure, what you want. What kind of application you have? Desktop or server side?

Comment: It's a plain perl script to be run from the command line or maybe cron.

Comment: so, you don't use this like server-side app and don't share it with anybody? just for yourself, yes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at [Net::StackExchange2](https://metacpan.org/module/Net%3a%3aStackExchange2)?

```
#for methods that require auth.
my $se = Net::StackExchange2->new(
    {
        site=>"stackoverflow",
        access_token => '<THE ACCESS TOKEN>' ,
        key => '<YOUR APP KEY>'
    }
);
```

It uses LWP::UserAgent. Even if you don't want to use the Net::StackExchange2 module directly, you have a good chance of finding some good example code to borrow from.

Comment: I think I might want to use this. Thank you, I don't know how it escaped my notice.